# Why do functions run even when they are not called?

Tags: google-apps-script

I hope this question finds you well.

Here is a Google Apps Script in its entirety:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

When I "Run" this script from `https://script.google.com/`, I am returned the following:

```
Execution log

5:23:46 PM Notice Execution started
5:23:46 PM Info hello
5:23:46 PM Notice Execution completed
```

As I have not called `myFunction` I would not expect to see `"hello"` in the Execution Log. Yet it is there. Why? And is there a way to make Google Apps Script behave like all other imperative programming environments in the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a script in the AppsScript runner, I assume you are hitting the `Run` menu item (or perhaps the `Debug` item). When you do this, you also need to look at which function name is selected in the function name drop-down list, to the right of that `Run` menu item (after the `Debug` menu item).

Whichever function is selected (and saved) will be executed. If you only have one function in the entire script, it will be selected by default.

[image]

There is no way to select "no function" in the script runner.

(And if you have no functions in your script, then the drop-down is greyed out and simply displays `No functions`.)

Comment: If there is only one function it is run. Otherwise, you have to select the script before the run button is available.